# how to run HTTPS website on local without any browser warning

Tags: java, https, web, localhost, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run website/service with https enabled on my localhost. but no matter what chrome/firefox always give me warning that certificate is not trusted and i have to by pass it.

is there any solution to it.

Comment: Down-voted for not being a *programming* question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -3):

After trying lot of options and googling a lot i finally found the following blog which worked like a charm

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec